# blocked by CORS policy on the browser working on postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm trying to fetch data from an API using reactJS, I used postman to test the API and it returns a JSON, but when I try from my reactJS application the web browser returns this error.

**"Access to fetch at 'http://XX.XX.XX.XX*/v1/shipping' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."**

Does anyone know why it's not working in the browser, but it works on postman?

[web browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1wQS.png)

[postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IswT8.png)

Here is the fetch function.

```
   fetchingData = () => {
    const bodyReq = {
      "bu":"",
      "customer":"",
      "start_time":"",
      "end_time":"",
      "serial_number":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      }
    fetch("http://XX.XX.XX.XX/v1/shipping", {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({bodyReq}),
    })
      .then(response => {response.json()
      console.log(response, 'Response')})
      .then(
        (response) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: response.items
          });
          console.log(response, 'Response')
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
          console.log(error, 'RESerror')
        }
      )
  }
```

This is the response I'm expecting from the API

```
{
    "code": 201,
    "error_code": 0,
    "msg": [
        {
            "bu": "XXXX",
            "carton_no": "XXXXXX",
            "container_no": "XXXXXX",
            "container_type": null,
            "cust_no": "XXXXXX",
            "emp_no": "XXXXXX",
            "group_name": "XXXXXX",
            "in_station_time": "XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX",
            "line_name": "XXXXXX",
            "mo_number": "XXXXXX",
            "model_name": "XXXXXX",
            "pallet_no": "XXXXXX",
            "plate_no": null,
            "po_number": "XXXXXX",
            "qa_no": "N/A",
            "serial_number": "XXXXXX",
            "ship_address": "XXXXXX",
            "ship_mothod": "XXXXXX",
            "version_code": "XXXXXX"
        },
        {
            "bu": "XXXX",
            "carton_no": "XXXXXX",
            "container_no": "XXXXXX",
            "container_type": null,
            "cust_no": "XXXXXX",
            "emp_no": "XXXXXX",
            "group_name": "XXXXXX",
            "in_station_time": "XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX",
            "line_name": "XXXXXX",
            "mo_number": "XXXXXX",
            "model_name": "XXXXXX",
            "pallet_no": "XXXXXX",
            "plate_no": null,
            "po_number": "XXXXXX",
            "qa_no": "N/A",
            "serial_number": "XXXXXX",
            "ship_address": "XXXXXX",
            "ship_mothod": "XXXXXX",
            "version_code": "XXXXXX"
        }
    ],
    "request": "POST /v1/shipping"
}
```

*note: I had to censure some data because is confidential data from the enterprise.

Comment: Yes, CORS is a security feature employed by browsers, Postman (curl, whatever) doesn't care.
While developing, you can just disable CORS check in your browser.

Comment: Is it an external api or your own api?

Comment: Guessing you did not search the error message.

Comment: @onuriltan is an external api, not my own.

Comment: @epascarello I did search about the error, but I was trying to see if I could do something about it because is not my api and I can't change configurations in the server.

Comment: okay, that's a great idea, to disable CORS, how do you do that in chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser environment is different from Postman. A browser has security features that Postman doesn't have and CORS is one of those.

If you want to understand how CORS work, check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell a browser to let a web application running at one origin (domain) have permission to access selected resources from a server at a different origin. A web application executes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a different origin (domain, protocol, or port) than its own origin.

Comment: okay, that's a great idea, to disable CORS, how do you do that in chrome?  This answer doesn't tell you how to solve it?

Comment: You can't disable CORS in the browser. The OP seemed confused by the fact that it was working on Postman, so I pointed out that his setup was not necessarily correct just because it worked on Postman. I also provided information pointing to a possible issue with different origins. I would say those are good leads.